# Formula for the Previous or Prior Value

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to highlight the rows based on the previous/Prior values. Please see the attached image for sample data
[Image of Crystal report sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU1Yx.png)

I want to highlight the Row if any event or events prior to any event has the same Sch time but different ETA. In my case "1 Sir Winston "would be the highlighted row

if({@Activity})='P/U' and ({@Sch_Time}) = previous ({@Sch_Time}) 
and ({@Addr}) <> Previous  ({@Addr})

and ({@ETATime}) > previous ({@ETATime}) then crRed else crNoColor

Comment: You're going to need the change your logical structure somehow.  The `Previous()` function can only retrieve the record (or row) immediately before the current record.  In your example the last last record where `{@Activity} = "P/U"` was 3 records prior to the current record, and therefore is out of scope for the `Previous()` function.

Comment: Is there any other solution in Crystal reports? Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

One option that might be possible would be to use a Shared or Global Variable.  [Here is a link to a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/crystal_reports_creating_variables.htm) on variables in Crystal Report if you are not familiar with them.

By using a variable you could store data from the last record that met your criteria.  For example, the following formula would store the values for `{@Sch_Time}` and `{@ETATime}` the last time `{@Activity} = "P/U"`.

```
Shared StringVar schTime;
Shared StringVar etaTime;
Shared StringVar address;

If {@Activity} = "P/U" Then
    schTime := {@Sch_Time}
    etaTime := {@ETATime}
    address := {@Addr}
Else
    schTime := schTime
    etaTime := etaTime
    address := {@Addr};
```

You would use this formula in a Formula Field, and then place it in a section of the report that prints each record.

The in sections that follow you can use the following formula to control the background color to highlight records.

```
Shared StringVar schTime;
Shared StringVar etaTime;
Shared StringVar address;

If {@Activity} = "P/U" and {@Sch_Time} = schTime and {@Addr} <> address and {@ETATime} > etaTime
then
    crRed
else
    crNoColor;
```

There are some nuances of this approach that may be problematic for you though.  For example, it can only store the values of the variables for the last record where `{@Activity} = "P/U"`.  Once a new records is encountered where this statement is true, the values of the variables will update with the values from the new record.

Without know more about your specific requirements I can't say for certain that this approach will work for you.  I think this problem would be easier to solve outside of the crystal report and in the database that you retrieve the data from.  For example you could create a stored procedure that selects your data and uses SQL to create a column that contains boolean values to indicate whether each row should be highlighted or not.

I'm not sure how much more help I can be though.  It might be a good idea to try something along the lines of what I've suggested and maybe ask a new question in regards to that approach, or wait and see if someone else has a better idea.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I really appreciate it. I still have some challenges like getting an error like "The remaining" at Else statement. I have added a semicolon (;) after the variables but no luck.  Also, the approach you have discussed here looks more appropriate to me. Thanks again.                 Shared StringVar schTime;
Shared StringVar etaTime;
Shared StringVar address;

If {@Activity} = "P/U" Then
    schTime := {@Sch_Time};
    etaTime := {@ETATime};
    address := {@Addr};
Else
      schTime := schTime;
      etaTime := etaTime;
      address := {@Addr};

Comment: Also, I tried to use this approach too:   if({@Activity})='P/U' and ({@Sch_Time}) = previous ({@Sch_Time}) 
//and ({@Addr}) <> Previous  ({@Addr}) 

 and ({@ETATime}) > previous ({@ETATime}) then {@Addr}

Comment: One thing to be aware of with the semicolon in Crystal Syntax.  A semicolon always indicates the end of a line or block of code.  So in the structure of an If..Then..Else block, as soon as Crystal Reports encounters a semicolon, it will parse that as the end of the If..Then..Else block of code.  That's why my example only had a semicolon after the final variable was assigned a value in the Else section of the code.

Comment: Thanks again, now I am getting the same error in the If statement starting at etaTime :={@ETSTime} (in the 6th row)